# Select statement getting error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a `SELECT` statement that is suppose to get a list of the top 3 matches, but it's getting an error for some reason. When I said top 3 matches, I don't mean just three rows. I mean rows that has the top 3 matches. So, something like this:

```
10
10
9
8
8
8
```

would be the top 3 matches, since 10,9,and 8 are the top highest. Please take a look at my code:

```
SELECT input, 
(input LIKE '% Hello %') as 'matches' 
FROM allData 
HAVING matches > '0' 
AND char_length(input) <= '50'
AND `matches` in 
(select distinct `matches`
from allData
order by `matches` desc
limit 3);
```

Comment: What is you error? This seems to just be a SQL/mysql question; no PHP/mysqli issues.

Comment: MySQL does not allow `LIMIT` in subqueries.  You cannot do what you want that way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any solutions?

Comment: @chris85 What gordon said.

Comment: It's good if you provide sample data & desired result.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Can we have having clause without Group by Clause in MYSQL? It seems issue to me..

Comment: @NitinTripathi . . . Yes.  It is a MySQL extension and it behaves like a WHERE` clause, but you can use column aliases defined in the `SELECT``.  In other databases, you would just use a subquery, but MySQL materializes subqueries, so there is a big performance hit with that approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot put limits in subqueries. If you want to achieve this, split this query into two queries. Make your subquery first and put the result from subquery into the main query.